# Update storage child name and database child name

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I have a structure like so:

```
{
  AllUsers: {

      76f4bd92-1fcd-4b4d-86c5-66b7e2822def: { 

            Users Username: { //change the name here

                -LCdF2QJ5c46lRnndtmY: { 
                    count: 1,
                    dateTime: 1526479204163,
                    name: "picture1",
                    url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/",
                },
                -LCdF2QJ5c46lRnndtmQ: {
                    count: 2,
                    dateTime: 1526479204163,
                    name: "picture2",
                    url: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/",
                }
            }
      }
  }
}
```

It's basically the same for my firebase storage and database, I am trying to allow the user to change their username and it updates in the paths here where it says `Users Username`

I have tried a few things similar:

```
final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("AllUsers").child(uuid);
final DatabaseReference dataBaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("AllUsers").child(uuid).child(currentName);

storageReference.child(newName);
dataBaseReference.equalTo(newName);
```

But it's not updating. Can anyone help, I feel I'm missing something important lol.

Comment: Start by adding error handling. You should include a .catch() on the end of your calls to determine why it's failing. Note that security rules would also be crucial here for determining possible causes. And you haven't indicated which operation fails. Also, your calls to .child() and .equalTo() aren't doing anything. Unclear why those are included here or what is expected from them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting, im just unsure on how to update values that are essentially paths/directories so i dont quite understand where to start, the catch is obviously a good place. Thank you will give it a try :)

Comment: equalTo() method is not used to update values in Firebase as far as I know. You should find where to update by adding a ValueEventListener to your DatabaseReference and inside that you should use setValue() method.

Comment: You can't change a key in firebase. You will have to move/copy your data to a new key (username) and delete the old one.

Comment: I shortly realised this @AndréKool and have done so, thank you, its probably a red flag if you need to do this anyway lol